# Is a visa necessary to travel to Korea from Japan?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea

I'm a student from India and I'll be travelling to Japan on a student visa and stay there for 3 months. I'd like to visit South Korea at the end of my studies and stay there for a week or so, and then return to my home country, India from Korea. Do I need to get a visa to travel to Korea? And is it possible for me to return to India with or without it?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Visa requirements depend first and foremost on your citizenship; can we assume you hold an Indian passport?

Answer (score 1):

As an Indian citizen, you will need a visa to visit Korea. You're not eligible for the 30-day exemption, as you would need a valid visa from Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the United States.

However, once you get a visa for Korea, you can fly onwards to India.